# How do I prove $\lim_{x\to\infty} ((\frac{x}{x+k})^x)=\frac{1}{e^k}$

Tags: limits

How do I prove this equation?
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} ((\frac{x}{x+k})^x)=\frac{1}{e^k}$$

Comment: Your attempt please...

Comment: This may help $e^{\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \ln(f(x))}$

Comment: I would say $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty} (\frac{x}{x+k})^x=\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac1{(1+\frac{k}{x})^x}=\cdots$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $ (\frac{n}{n+k})^n = (1-\frac{k}{n+k})^{n+k}(1-\frac{k}{n+k})^{-k}$